# Inserting a list of over 200,000 words in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, logistics

I'm working on a React Native application that involves choosing words from a list of 200,000. I already have this list of words, but I'm having trouble putting it into my application. At first, I wanted to put them in a separate file and read them into an array, but React Native does not have access to the fs node module. I tried copying and pasting them in directly, but this is messy and cumbersome. Are there any other ways that this can be done? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can store the array in a separate file, export it, then import it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply Store the data in `json` in a seperate file, And then `import` it using the `import` statement.

Here is an example.

***data.json file***

```
{
  "name": "saroj",
  "age": 180
}
```

***app.js***

```
import json from "./data.json";

function App() {
  console.log(json);
  return <View style={styles.app}></View>;
}
```

***the output is :***

```
{name: "saroj", age: 180}
```

**According to question**

you can store the list of over 200,000 words in an array in a json file like wise:

```
{
"wordList": [
"word1",
"word2",
"word3",
..
...
....
"word200000"

]
}
```

thank you.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I'm still having a bit of trouble understanding how to add the list of words to the json though. Would I put them in an array in a key-value pair? Ideally, the words would each be on their own line

Comment: @dannnny you can also directly export array instead of json.

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi That makes sense! The problem I'm having with this is that if too many things are on the same line, VS Code stops tokenizing them and doesn't process them well. I think that they will probably all have to be on their own line.

Comment: @SarojRegmi forgot to tag you above, sorry!

Comment: You can use other tools like Notepad++ or MS Excel to format your array @dannnny

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi exporting as an array would also be a good approach, but when the data is a little big i don't think so making a js file to hold it in an array would be a good idea. And dannnny i have edited the answer to suite your requirements.

Comment: @dannnny, its fine, would you mind upvoting and accepting the answer, if it was helpful it will also help other peoples too.

Comment: @SarojRegmi the code u modified, is that a valid json? I suppose you have to put in a key and then value can be an array.

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi sry my bad, let me fix it out real quick, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Just accepted! @SarojRegmi Thank you for your help! I think the answer you gave will work now. I don't have the ability to upvote yet, but I'll come back and upvote your answer and comments when I do!

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi Could only tag one person above, but same to you!